# Swift - Take Photo or Choose existing

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

Whenever I am using an app and it asks for a photo, something like this pops up: 
[image]

Do any of y'all have a reference for what is actually going on here? Is there some built in function or open source library that is used for this? I can't seem to find any specific resources on the interwebs.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your basic modal alert to me. Nothing much more. The *real* question is what you see when you tp "Take Photo" or "Choose Existing" - are they using UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your screenshot you see an [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UIAlertController) with two Actions:

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: nil)
let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Existing", style: .default handler: nil)

actionSheet.addAction(camerAction)
actionSheet.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
```

To access the Photo Library or to use the Camera to shoot a new picture, you might want to have a look at the [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller).

Comment: Exactly what I needed - it's a UIAlertController. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a `UIActionController` dynamically by checking if a camera source is available and then adding the relevant action to the controller:

```
let actionController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        print("User tapped 'Take Photo'")
    })
    actionController.addAction(action)
}
```

You'll also need to create another action for "Choose Existing" and the "Cancel" button.

Then simply show the action controller from your current view controller.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the library is presenting a `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyle` enum of `actionSheet`. Depending on the choice, it then instantiate a `UIImagePickerController` with `sourceType` `photoLibrary` or `camera`.

This is standard behavior for getting an image for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Full code with cancel button, like on your screenshot

```
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Existing", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    actionSheet.addAction(cameraAction)
    actionSheet.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```